# User Control with Viewbox - binding Path Data

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, viewbox

I have a usercontrol that contains the following Xaml:

```
<Viewbox Style="{StaticResource shapeViewboxStyle}">
        <Canvas Width="32" Height="32" Margin="5">
            <Path Data="{Binding Path=PathData}"/>
        </Canvas>
 </Viewbox>
```

In the code-behind I expose a dependency property:

```
    public string PathData
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(PathDataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PathDataProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PathDataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("PathData", typeof(string), 
            typeof(ContentItemHeader), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

What I want to do is pass in a string with the path data when I insert the user control.

```
PathData="M 0,0 V 32 H 32 V 0 H 0 M 0,8 H 32"
```

But this doesn't work. I get no image at all. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the Binding's RelativeSource to the UserControl instance:

```
<Path Data="{Binding PathData, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
      ... />
```

Comment: That worked! If I understand this correctly, what this says is don't use the inherited DataContext, instead use the UserControl itself?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an inherited DataContext in your example. Setting `PathData="M 0,0 V 32 H 32 V 0 H 0 M 0,8 H 32"` does not set a DataContext. In general, a UserControl should neither directly access an inherited DataContext, not should it explicitly set its own. It should expose dependency properties, which are then bound to properties of an inherited DataContext when you use the control, like `<ContentItemHeader PathData="{Binding YourPath}"/>`.

Comment: I set the DataContext in the code-behind, but didn't show that. `LayoutRoot.DataContext = this;`